# Notify user of majority of wrongly tagged questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

I looked at the first page of [model-view-controller questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) and of the 30 listed, 25 or should not have the [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) and instead should have [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc).  I'd be amazed if this isn't the case for the majority of model-view-controller tagged questions.

Should we have a feature that can pop up if certain criteria are detected and there is a huge chance to let the user know that they may have incorrectly tagged a question.

For instance, the criteria could be if [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) with ( [razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor) or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) then notify [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)).  I'd imagine it could be easy for moderators using an web UI to create these notification criteria.

Additionally, I guess there is no real easy way to check the other 2,100+ questions to see if they are mis-tagged.

Comment: There's likely no automated process, but what's wrong with editing one or two?

Comment: I re-tag at least 5, and usually about 10 a day :)

Comment: I'd say the thing to do here is turn the discussion towards creating a decent stack of example cases to backup the usefulness of the feature with - complete with the criteria. Having just the one is not going to persuade anyone to go invest design and development time. And that's where it gets dicy, because the criteria for other cases are probably not as clear-cut as this one. Take the good old "java is not javascript" example; how would you catch that?

Comment: The problem is that `mvc` is a synonym for `model-view-controller`. So people who type `asp.net` `mvc` get `asp.net` `model-view-controller`.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366942/can-we-warn-against-model-view-controller