# Can we warn against [model-view-controller]?

Tags: feature-request, tags

It seems pretty obvious to me that people *don't read tags description*, specially when you see tags used whose excerpt start with "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

A very common case for this problem is the [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) tag, which states:

> Model–View–Controller (MVC) is an architectural pattern used in software engineering. For Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, please use [asp.net-mvc] tag instead. For Spring MVC, please use [spring-mvc] tag instead.

Since I'm mostly watching the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, I always re-tag every question I see on the feed. Yet, looking at the 15 newest questions tagged with [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller):

- Questions 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14 and 15 are about ASP.NET MVC
- Questions 2 and 11 are related to Spring MVC
- Questions 8, 9 are not related to the pattern nor any MVC framework

I am sure I could find thousands of examples since the tag currently sits at over 25k questions.

Can we add a warning like it's done to the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag or something?

Comment: Oh, warn against *the tag*...

Comment: This request supersedes https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337065