# Synonymize [models] and [model]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/models) 2,489 Open Qs

> A model is an abstract representation of a real-life object or process. Models are a part of the popular MVC pattern, as well as a more general concept in the sciences for approximating behavior.

[model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model) 13,340 Open Qs

> Part of the MVC pattern, the Model manages the behaviour and data of the application.

Based on a very small sample of ~16,000 Qs either Usage guide would be equally applicable in all cases.

I can't see any good reason why we need a singular tag here. If you're working on 1000 models or 1, [models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/models)should be sufficient to describe what you're working on.

<sub>There are over 300 other such singular/plural pairs (listed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/1505120)) and picking each off individually with a separate meta Q & A would be to waste a vast amount of resources that could be better spent cleaning up the tags after synonymisation.</sub>

[We generally agree that network wide, the preferred tag is always the plural form unless there is some clear and compelling reason to use the singular version.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/600/4995) courtesy [Jeff Atwood](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/71/jeff-atwood).

Related: [Can we warn against [model-view-controller]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366942/can-we-warn-against-model-view-controller)

Answer (score 2):

From the tag wiki pages:

[model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model)

> > A model is an abstract representation of a real-life object or
> >     process. Models are a part of the popular MVC pattern, as well as a
> >     more general concept in the sciences for approximating behavior.
>
> A model is one of the three components of Model-View-Controller (MVC)
>   programming pattern that provides knowledge: data and how to work with
>   this data, responding to requests by changing its state.
>
> It can also refer to models in a more general scientific sense,
>   denoting a representation (generally a simplification) of how a
>   real-world process operates.

[models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/models)

> > Part of the MVC pattern, the Model manages the behaviour and data of
> >     the application.
>
> The MVC (Model, View, Controller) pattern separates objects into one
>   of three categories — models for maintaining data, views for
>   displaying all or a portion of the data, and controllers for handling
>   events that affect the model or view(s).
>
> Frameworks such as Laravel, Rails, Django and ASP.NET MVC apply this
>   pattern in the web development domain.

it is very clear that they mean the same thing and are being used for the same thing. Therefore the synonym would make complete sense.

I'm not sure if I agree with the plural part, but [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model) is the more widely used terminology while using the MVC framework. Therefore I've made [models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/models) the synonym of [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model).