# Is this a phase-out [model]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model)

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?

It's a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that is incredibly vague and as such, used willy-nilly pretty much everywhere (there are currently almost 19k questions with this tag applied). As such, it adds no value whatsoever - the specific MVC framework tag that almost always accompanies this one is far more useful.

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they **do not describe the content of the question**. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, **or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.)**.

To quote [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination#comment678513_324071) **(emphasis mine)**:

> ... despite popular belief a tag is not meant to drive traffic from outside to a post. **Tags are used by the experts to find the questions they can answer. Having tags that are cluttered with off-topic / low-quality stuff hinder them in providing valuable content.** If anything, tag curation is aimed at helping those experts and that helps visitors that happen to use a tag search as well.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, but again - incredibly vague. See also [duplode's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination#comment709859_324071):

> ... if tags truly had to "fail all of these tests", criterion #2 would mean that no on-topic tag should be burninated. I think it would be more adequate to say that failing at least one of the tests is a necessary, though not sufficient, condition for burnination. Shog's wording when explaining criterion #4 appears to support this interpretation: "Be aware though, this [criterion] need only be a death sentence when [...]" -- the point being that criterion #4 alone might suffice to seal the fate of a tag.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. Sometimes it's the model part of MVC, sometimes the model part of data or machine-learning models. For the former, the MVC framework in question will be a far more useful tag, and for the latter we already have [data-modelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-modelling) and [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) respectively (although I question the usefulness of those tags too - they also seem far too broad).

---

I appreciate that burninating a tag used on so many questions goes against the general burnination guidance, but this one is just taking up valuable disk space on SO's databases.

---

**edit:** comment about disk space was intended to be flippant, please stop "correcting" me regarding it.

**edit:** [I've opened a question about the burnination process here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402376/why-is-the-tag-burnination-process-so-strict)

Comment: How is it a meta-tag?

Comment: *"Taking up disk space"* - Nope. That's not a concern whatseoever.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with this - it's too ambiguous to be much use.

The tag usage guidance says,

> Part of the MVC pattern, the Model manages the behaviour and data of the application.

Technically, that's unambiguous, but I don't think that that "saves" the tag. In reality, the term "model" refers to all sorts of other things too, such as data models and Machine Learning models.

We could rename those uses of it [mvc-model] or something like that, and remove the other uses of this.

Comment: Hmmm... are there corresponding tags for the View and Controller parts of the [tag:model-view-controller] pattern?There's [tag:controller] and [tag:viewcontroller] plus lots of tags for specific implementations or uses of the pattern.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, technically all those have to be replaced with a single [tag:mvc] tag. It doesn't make difference whenever you are asking about model, controller or viewcontroller. There can't be an expert in model only, rather expert in [tag:mvc] or [tag:mvvm] (also has model), etc. only complete techology tags make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with burnination, as I think removing the tag would do more harm than good.  This additional burnination criteria for tags with over 1000 questions was not evaluated by the OP.

Additionally, All four tests must fail; OP has stated (vaguely) that it does not fail test #2.

While a tag with 19K questions in it no doubt has a not-insignificant number of wrongly tagged posts, there appears to have been no effort to even attempt to quantify them.  A [previous merge request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372605/synonymize-models-and-model) actually increased the number of posts with the [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model) tag, so it didn't seem to be perceived as problematic two years ago.  What has changed?

While I agree it is being used as a meta-tag contrary to the tag usage guidance, and it would be preferred to replace it with more relevant and specific tags, the effort required to do so simply isn't worth it, compared to much better uses of volunteer time.

My opinion might be swayed with a statistical [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model) summarizing the harm the current tag is doing and appropriate replacements vs. just deleting the tag.  As suggested by the [Burnination Process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination?noredirect=1&lq=1) meta post:

> If the tag isn't harmful, consider instead a divide and conquer approach to the problem by using one or more of these alternative strategies:
>
> - Tag merge/retag,
> - Tag synonyms,
> - Tag clean-up,
> - Tag wiki excerpt update,
> - Tag warning

Certainly one or more of these would be a good first step, but would require actually looking at a sample of the 19K tags to determine the best approach.

Without any such effort by the OP or someone else strongly in favor of burnination, I think this goes against the spirit of the [Criteria for Burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) as articulated by Shog9:

> If you're thinking that these criteria are gonna be pretty tedious to evaluate on a tag with thousands of questions in it, then you're absolutely right - which is why I'm pretty skeptical toward a lot of these requests on those rare occasions I take time to do it. If you're thinking that it's not worth the effort for tags that generally don't seem to be causing any problems, then you're sharper than half the folks throwing up these requests. If it looks like pointless busywork, it probably is pointless busywork...

And

> if it is clear that removing the tag will do more harm than good, then we should obviously not remove it.

It's not clear to me that removing the tag will not cause more harm than the negligible benefit it brings.  I could be convinced otherwise with any well reasoned data-supported argument from someone in support of deleting this tag on 19K questions.

Finally, to address OP's concern that the tag takes up "valuable disk space on SO's databases", I'll note that SO doesn't delete anything, and in fact retagging will only increase the amount of disk space used on SO's databases with the new revision of 19K questions.

Comment: I read Shog quotes backwards: we shouldn't spend efforts on these tags because these tags shouldn't exist in the first place. In other words, most of these tags should be obliterated rather than discussed, and unless show a clear, unambiguous benefit towards these questions being answered thanks to these tags, just zap it from existence. The later quote shows that this take makes sense.

Comment: @Braiam Perhaps it shouldn't have existed. But that's not the question now. The question is whether removing it from 19K questions would do more harm than good. Do you have a compelling argument that it would be beneficial to do so? I'd love to hear it.

Comment: That's a discussion that is not going anywhere. If it shouldn't exist on the first place, then removing it now from 5, 100, 1k or 1000k questions is a non-issue, as it would never cause harm by removing it since it never was of any benefit by keeping it.

Comment: @Braiam That hand-wavey answer still does not quantitatively evaluate the tag. I remain unconvinced.

Comment: @DanielWiddis What harm would it do to remove it? I can only imagine problems for questions with this as the only tag.

Comment: The harm in removal is always the time spent doing so, while other tags are neglected. Nobody's ever asking if they can go through questions and give them a bunch of good, relevant tags - they just do that. These removals chew up a lotta time and effort; if there's no perceivable benefit, then that's just wasted.

Comment: @Shog9 exactly, which is why simply sniping it out of existence is the most effective way of dealing with these. For me, the biggest waste of time is discussing about it, rather than just removing it.

Comment: @Braiam if you are so eager to snipe the tag, perhaps you, or the OP, can follow the [Burnination Process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) requirements for tags with over 1000 questions, as I've stated repeatedly.  The tag won't be removed unless the process is followed.

Comment: I've updated the question with some quotes supporting my understanding of the intention of tags and the burnination process, as well as opened a new question regarding burnination (linked at end of this question).

Comment: @DanielWiddis that's not what is needed. That process won't achieve what is needed. What is needed is a developer to do `update post set tags = replace(tags, '<model>', '') where tags like '%<model>%'`. There's no process like that.