# Why is the tag burnination process so strict?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/70345

The currently-documented process for proposing burnination is incredibly strict, narrow, and essentially appears to be focused on **preventing** burnination, especially for tags applied to large numbers of questions.

This, to me, seems to be orthogonal to the goal of curating Stack Overflow: if the community deems a tag pointless, why not get rid of it? Yet the burnination guidance explicitly advises against this:

> It might have been preferable to run this process purely on voting, but that would inevitably lead to trouble. Your distaste for a frustrating game shouldn't result in the destruction of otherwise-valid tags.

This appears to ignore the will of the community, which is orthogonal to Stack Overflow's stated goals.

All in all, the burnination process seems convoluted and contradictory. I would appreciate if someone very familiar with the process (preferably Shog, since he originally wrote that answer) could provide some rationale here.

Comment: I think a big issue is that burnination takes both significant community effort and a bit of organization. If it was the sort of thing that could be done with a single button click, requirements could have been loose since the process is easy to carry out, but it isn't - every question has to be analyzed individually by those doing cleanup. So, narrowing the requirements helps thin the field.

Comment: @CertainPerformance **Why** does *every* question "need" to be analysed? Who determines this "need"?

Comment: See step 4 of the process in the linked A. *The [tag:tag] tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and... <various cleanup guidelines>.* Just deleting a bad tag outright isn't the best solution because sometimes salvageable questions need to be edited / retagged with something more appropriate, and each question needs to be considered individually.

Comment: Is the question [Should all burninate-requests follow a template?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316066/11682469) and its answers useful? Also related: [The burnination criteria need a complete rework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380183/11682469)

Comment: That still doesn't explain why **every individual question** needs to be reviewed. My process would simply be: run SEDE query to find out how many questions will be left untagged if a tag is burninated; add a more specific tag to *those* questions (in bulk if necessary); use bulk update to remove tag from every question that has it; burninate tag.

Comment: Thanks @JeanneDark. It seems that the consensus by certain members of the community is "burnination is difficult so we should avoid doing it". That doesn't fly for me in any way shape or form. If it's difficult, we must make it easier. If we need CMs to get involved, let's involve them. If the only way to do it is by firing N requests (where N is the number of questions) at SO's servers, then let's do that.

Comment: It could be that the idea is to **preserve value** when posts are useful to SO's goal: edit re-tag individual questions with the tag when salvageable, and close/delete the questions when not. That sort of thing just can't be done with a database query. (...yet)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Having to re-analyse **every question with that tag** is something that falls under "pointless busywork" in my books. If a question is good, it will likely be answered already, almost certainly because it uses other better tags; so removing the bad tag will do no harm. Conversely, on a question that has not been answered, the use of the bad tag is likely one of the reasons that question did not get more eyeballs... so removing the tag will again have no effect. Additionally, I strongly suspect a strong correlation between bad questions and ones with bad tags.

Comment: @IanKemp " add a more specific tag to those questions". If you would kindly share this algorithm, that would be neat. Its a pretty hard classification problem and I'm sure if you, have found a way to re-tag questions with high enough precision automatically, it would be very well received.

Comment: It can all be summed up in one sentence: because tag burnination is *destructive*. There need to be lots of safeguards against undertaking *destructive* processes.

Comment: I'm not sure how a 142-score (+153/-11) post is undermining the will of the community?

Comment: @TylerH you only approve of it because you didn't suffer from it :D

Answer (score 17):

The process is so strict because, before there was a process, there were many times when there were significant problems with how the removal was done, or nothing was done at all. Some of the problems included prominent cases where totally valid tags were removed within the day the Meta post was created. Repairing those mishaps was painstaking. The cases of nothing being done were clear from the backlog of requests.

The history is that the FAQ emerged from [Evaluation of SOCVR's Burnination Process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323121/evaluation-of-socvrs-burnination-process), where we basically tried to capture the intent of what burnination should be.

By having a process, we achieve:

- improved quality of burnination requests,
- some rules of thumb for streamlined handling of requests about tags with only a few questions,
- reduce the times when tag followers are surprised by tag removal,
- give subject matter experts a chance to chime in with advice and guidance,
- and have a common approach when a burnination is conducted.

After the FAQ was put in place, around 10 users participated in the [Trogdor chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor) to go over all open burnination requests and propose a call to action for each open request, varying from status-decline, through straight tag removal, to a full process burnination. A couple of mods then took that advice, validated the proposed actions and executed the portions of it which didn't require additional community involvement. That brought down the number of open requests substantially, leaving us with open requests which weren't really straightforward calls to remove a tag. Those burnination requests were the "complex" ones that didn't have a simple, straightforward solution.

Until September 2019, a steady stream of burnination requests were handled. Then events surrounding Stack Exchange took place which greatly reduced the willingness of many key people to spend large amounts of their spare time on a site that didn't care about its curators.

And here we are.

> the burnination process seems convoluted and contradictory.

I'm biased because I've helped author, execute, and invent substantial portions of that process. I still believe burnination is complex enough to be somewhat convoluted. We've always made edits to the FAQ if we noticed things were unclear, were misused, or lead to disasters. Yes, I would rather see users that just *stumble* on a perceived bad tag don't post a burnination request on Meta. So if the FAQ tries to prevent burnination, then that goal is achieved.

Keep in mind once a tag gets noticed for its badness, the tag has often had a chance to collect a good amount of crap. The burnination is also the clean-up, edit, closing, and deleting of accumulated low quality content that has accumulated in a poor tag.

If we agree that tags are primarily used by our experts in the community, so they can find the question they want to answer, then we should have a process that both protects those tags from being removed on a whim and allows the experts to invoke a community supported effort when their tag gets flooded with inappropriate questions.

It's not hard to remove tags. It is hard to remove the side effects of tags that cause problems. If you haven't done a burnination, I suggest to do so, preferably a small (< 50 questions) one which has clear support for what should be done with the tag and questions. Remember that the goal is usually not *just* the removal of the tag, but is also the clean-up of questions which are/were in the tag: editing all of each on-topic question's title, body, and tags; closing questions which are off-topic for Stack Overflow; and deleting accumulated low quality content which has accumulated in that tag.

Comment: I'll also add that sometimes without a meta-consensus doing a "tag clear-up" despite their best attentions can also be destructive to the site.

Comment: "By adding a tad of process we achieve"? Really, really? There only thing I've achieved by participating on these burnination discussion is souring arguments.

Answer (score 2):

"Every individual question needs to be reviewed" because tags mean "I'm looking for solution using X". If you simply remove the tag X that critical piece of information may be gone from the post - I don't see how any automated solution can resolve that problem right now.

I.e. I propose to delete "JavaScript" tag - with so many question tagged with it it can't realistically provide much value short of "post belongs to SO". Without careful review whole bunch of questions will change its meaning from "how to do it in JavaScript" to overly broad how to do that.

Answer (score -5):

> Why is the tag burnination process so strict?

Because it's inefficient. But why it's is inefficient? Because it's strict. But why it's strict? Because it's inefficient.

That sounds like a circular argument, but it really isn't. Yes, it's absurd, but it's the most accurate representation of the situation.

The burnination process is so strict because it requires several hours of evaluation and discussion, because right now the only way to remove a tag is to put up a compelling argument, hoping no one cares enough to make *any* counter argument, get lucky to be featured in the community bulletin, and that <s>senpai</s> a moderator notices your post and feature it. Now you may say that this is the "strict" part of it, but it's actually the inefficient part that you see as "strict".

Now, the process was not created to prevent busybody request but turn it up to 11 the little bar we had as friction that asking those 4 questions (remember, the [original was a test to burninate if any tag failed the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#comment896615_239191), which SO modified to that it must fail every criteria).

This criteria was created to mask a inefficiency and one of the biggest asymmetric systems of effect and counter effect: while tag creation is trivial, tag removal is freaking expensive. You only need to add a tag to a question to create it, but you must edit and remove the tag from each question it is attached to (is O(1) vs O(n)). Obviously, that implies serious work, for which there's no tooling in the system to make it easier.

So, why is the removal of a tag so difficult in SO: for lack of accessible tooling that makes it easier. The perfect tooling would be a bulk adding/removing tag tool. The adding aspect accepts Posts Id's with a tag, and the removal a tag name which returns a list of Posts Id's with the removed tag. The observant would notice that this effectively makes trivial any rollback and gives the community a good way to make the process cheaper while keeping accountability. If we fix the inefficiency at the base of the bulk tag actions, you will see every other process we built upon it to become irrelevant and unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not sure that just because it would be possible to do a rollback makes the process obsolete. It's also possible to un-delete a post, but it rarely happens.

Comment: @Scratte the process exist to prevent "significant problems with how the removal was done". A clean rollback would remove this problems and make the process obsolete. The only reason why un-deleting is rare is because most of it is removed by Roomba.