# Taking a look in the [mirror]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

This is more a discussion point rather than a flat-out burninate request. The problem here is the ambiguity rather than the content, necessarily - the [mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirror) tag is used for a variety of overlapping, but completely separate topics.

Even in the first page we have questions covering:

- Mirroring a vector in R
- Replacing a RAID1 failed mirror disk (OT for SO)
- Mirroring a Git repository
- Mirroring a video (as in flipping it)
- FTP mirror server
- Debian package mirror

If we look at the criteria:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, it's ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It depends on what concept we're going with - mostly, yes (especially if we take the most common usage of the tag, the Unity mirror networking library.)

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

As-is no, as it could mean any one of a handful of things.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, definitely not.

I'm leaning towards saying that the unity mirror questions should be retagged as [mirror-networking] or similar, the server ones as [mirror-server], and the other ones don't need to use any variant of the mirror tag at all - but curious as to other's thoughts.

Comment: A good start would be to add a usage guidance (yes, I know, people ignore them). The description clearly states its intended usage: *Mirror is a high level Networking API for Unity (...)*.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree, if we decide the tag is best reserved for the unity library then that would definitely be the best start. Though as you say, it often doesn't have much impact for people asking questions...

Comment: *if we decide the tag is best reserved for the unity library* IMO, yes it is. A visible guidance at least sanctions removing the tag from other questions in the future.

Comment: "unity" is highly ambiguous. Is it [GNOME's Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface))? Probably not [the C# library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) or [Unity Application Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Enterprise_Library#Version_5.0_Silverlight_Integration_Pack).

Comment: The only useful usage that can be extracted from this tag is [unity-mirror-networking]. Without the prefix, mirror-networking would lend itself to confusion still. The other usages already have tags when they are on topic.

Comment: @PeterMortensen In this case, it's definitely the C# Unity, the game engine Unity. I would argue that that's probably the most common usage of the term on SO... especially in light of the fact that SO tags which contain "*unity*" are essentially entirely about the game engine.

Comment: Mirror, [mirror] on the wall - what's the worst tag of them all?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica you will vomit with the rapid flashing of images that is needed to show them all.

Comment: @zcoop98 yet the SO tag is [unity3d], of which [unity] is an alias.

Comment: Another day, another s***ty tag that will never get burninated or renamed because doing so will take too much time and effort, because Stack Exchange Inc. hates its moderators.

Comment: @IanKemp actually, moderators hate themselves. They made a process as rubegoldbergy as possible so that nothing gets done. [I tried to fix it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402384/792066)

Comment: Nobody's asking questions about ["mirrors" used for reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_(programming))? Sad.

Comment: note: I've retagged those **Unity3D Mirror** (networking) questions as [tag:unity3d-mirror]... just so nobody gets the idea that "mirror-networking", as a tag, is a thing (it should not be and isn't)