# A single burnination for [multiple-models]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[multiple-models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-models)

Another meta tag with a grand total of 90 questions across multiple knowledge domains, and no usage guidance. Not even going to bother going through the burninate request checklist, as it's pretty obvious that this one should be gone ASAP.

Comment: Should it be replaced with anything else? Does it ever appear as the only tag on the question?

Comment: @Dharman every question appears to have at least one other tag.  We can nuke it from orbit.

Comment: There are [multiple-models] for burnination.

Comment: If you aren't going to bother spending time evaluating the questions in more detail, why should the community bother to spend time on your request?

Comment: I went ahead and burninated since it was clear the tag was bad and it had 90 questions. But we do prefer the checklist be used. I suspect it got some downvotes if only for that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm a little unclear about what this is even referring to, beyond the fact that the OPs are trying to use more than one of some kind of model somehow. This certainly does not appear to uniquely identify a specific knowledge domain.

This is so unclear and vague that it's of little to no use. In fact, none of the top answerers have answered more than 1 question in the tag, and only 1 of the top askers has used the tag more than once, which suggests that it's not really helping anyone - in most cases, it appears to be sheer coincidence that someone happened to have a question where that tag even sort of applied, and no one appears to be using it to find questions to answer.

I say we burninate this.

Comment: Just because "no one appears to be using it to find questions to answer" doesn't mean there's not another (watched) tag that should have been used, and retagging is preferable to deleting.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with "gone ASAP" burnination primarily because the OP is "not going to even bother" to take the time to evaluate the burnination criteria.

I don't disagree that the name of this tag is poor, but renaming/merging may be a better option, that OP hasn't bothered to evaluate.

OP complains about "multiple knowledge domains" but after I actually bothered to browse through all 90 questions (at the time OP posted, there seem to be less than 50 now), I found only two  primary domains (yes, technically that's multiple but it's not "so unclear and vague" it can't be dealt with methodically). The questions mostly addressed either ensemble models in ML (primarily with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) tags, or relating to R), or the model-view-controllor design pattern, primarily with multiple models/views in web technologies, which require special treatment programmatically.

There are legitimate programming concerns adapting MVC to multiple models that are covered in [various tutorials](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/) online in addition to the SO questions of concern here. The fact that [this tutorial for R](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) has an entire section dealing with "Many Models" or the presence multiple [articles about comparing multiple models](https://towardsdatascience.com/quickly-test-multiple-models-a98477476f0) in ML indicates this concept should have some tag associated with it, rather than simply deleting users' attempts to tag it.

I think some/most of the ML-based questions could be retagged with either the [ensemble-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ensemble-learning) tag or, if that's thought too off-topic, the specific algorithm relevant to a combination of ML models.

The majority of the remainder of the tags are associated with the model-view-controller design pattern, asking on-topic questions about dealing with multiple views, mostly either in asp.net or ruby on rails. [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) and [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) don't quite cover that design pattern by themselves. The [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) tag doesn't have a variant that deals with multiple models or multiple views, and there has been [some discussion that tag shouldn't be used anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366942/can-we-warn-against-model-view-controller).  There may be some other existing tag that is more specific/relevant.

There may be other tags that a small retagging effort could address.  A small amount of time by subject matter experts in the relevant technologies could easily clean this up.

Saying simply that "this one should be gone ASAP" without any effort in evaluating other options does not meet the level of effort that a burninate request should have before asking the community to spend time on it.

Comment: You make some valid points, but there was no real tag to merge this into. Merges work best when there's some clear overlap between tags, and there's no one tag it really overlapped with. Everything is retagged now, but ML models != MVC models != ORM models